# Aligning Div in css

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to align `div` and all my efforts using `float` and `margins` didn't bring what I want. So I thought this is the right place

basically looping the below in `Foreach`:

```
<div class="comment_name">@Html.displayName</div>
<div class="comment_time">@Html.formattedDateTime(item.dTime.Value)</div>
<div class="comment_body">@item.displayComments</div>
```

and am trying to display like the below text:

```
Dispaly Name , 11 Feb 2013: User entered comment.
```

What should be the `CSS` to make it work?

***Updated after Span answer***

Span worked. But am having issues if the length of comment is long. am getting like below

```
Dispaly Name , 11 Feb 2013:The example will show you how to implement a read-only grid. This article tries to answer the following question
```

but which should be

```
Dispaly Name , 11 Feb 2013:The example will show you how to implement a read-only grid.
                            this article tries to answer the following question
```

Comment: setting "display:inline-block" should be fine

Comment: only `float: left` the first two?

Comment: If you want to make it in one line you could use <span> instead, which is an "inline-element"

Comment: float left all and clear left on comment_name

Comment: insertusernamehere made a point, just use <span>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float: left` on every div and `clear: left;` for the first one;

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9mfR8/

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

.comment_name{    
   clear: left;
}
```

Or you can use `display: inline-block;` for the three divs and enclose them in a container div (that is `display: block` by default and will force a "new line"),

Comment: your clear right does nothing - you have no right floated elements you would need clear left on comment_name, your fiddle only works as the text is long enough to naturally take up a line

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would say use `<span>`s instead of `<div>`s as they are already inline elements:

```
<span>@Html.displayName</span>
<span>@Html.formattedDateTime(item.dTime.Value)</span>
<span>@item.displayComments</span>
```

If you want to stick to `<div>`s use:

```
display: inline;
```

or if the single containers have for example a fixed width:

```
display: inline-block;
```

---

### Edit

To achieve the result in your updated question, you can use this:

**HTML**

```
<span>Dispaly Name,</span>
<span>11 Feb 2013:</span>
<span> The example will show you how to implement a read-only grid. This article tries to answer the following question.
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    vertical-align: top;
}

span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/jkZeZ/

Comment: +1 : I would use <span>s instead of <div>s as they are already inline elements

Comment: @user2067567 I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following should achieve what you require:

```
.comment_name {
    display: inline-block;
}

.comment_time {
    display: inline-block;
}

.comment_body {
    display: inline-block;
}
```